# Yosemite: Safari's window is too wide

Tags: safari, macos

I'm a web developer and like to develop with a narrow browser window to somehow emulate how my website will look on a mobile phone. With pre-Yosemite-Safari it was possible to create such a narrow window that you could easily judge the look of your site on mobile. With Yosemite, this seems to be impossible. Any suggestions?

[image: Picture from an iPhone.]

Picture from an iPhone. I'd like to replicate this on the desktop. Note the line break after "Analytical"

[image: Situation on the desktop after upgrading to Yosemite]

Situation on the desktop after upgrading to Yosemite

Comment: You could install Xcode and use the iOS simulator that's built-in to run Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable "Develop" menu in Preferences > Advanced.

Then you can select choose the User Agent to be iPhone or whatever.
[image]

And then resize the window appropriately:

[image]

**Edit**: This doesn't get around the minimum width for the window. Here is a workaround. Go to View > Show Sidebar. This pulls out the sidebar, which can be resized making the viewport smaller.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I put it wrong, but following your advice doesn't let me make the window narrower than without changing the user agent. Before Yosemite, I could make Safari almost half as narrow as now which came very close to the width of a Safari on an iPhone 5.

On my iPhone, when I visit Wikipedia, the width only allows for a little bit more than "Today's featured article" to be displayed and the first line of today's article features only the two words "The Analytical" before the line break.

Comment: I see what you're saying. See my edit at the bottom.

Comment: This workaround should do for now. I also submitted my issue to Apple in the hopes that they will change this behaviour back.

Comment: Doing it this way is a workaround anyways. To get more accurate rendering, you should run the iOS simulator and launch Safari from there or just test on your phone.